# @Route directive not working--what am I doing wrong?

Tags: symfony, routes, url-routing, symfony-2.2

I used composer.phar to install Symfony 2.2.1 standard edition, and then I used the app/console utility to generate a "ClientBundle".

I'm trying to define my routes using the @Route annotation.  Here's my controller:

```
namespace ScrumBoard\ClientBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/my/route/path")
     */
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('ScrumBoardClientBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

And my bundles are defined like this:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
        new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
        new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
        new Acme\HelloBundle\AcmeHelloBundle(),
        new ScrumBoard\ClientBundle\ScrumBoardClientBundle(),
    );

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}
```

You can see that SensioFrameworkExtraBundle is included in my list of bundles.

However, when I go to http://symfony2.localhost/app_dev.php/my/route/path I get

```
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /my/route/path"" at C:\webdev\scrum-whiteboard\symfony-quickstart\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 3609
```

So, obviously I'm missing something... how do I get the @Route annotations working?

JFYI, if I go to http://symfony2.localhost/config.php I can see that Symfony2 is working.  I get the "Welcome to your new Symfony project." message, and no config errors are noted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work.  I don't know if this is correct.  I had to do two things.

First, I added this to my routing.yml file:

```
ScrumBoardClientBundle:
  resource: "@ScrumBoardClientBundle/Controller/"
  type:     annotation
  prefix:   /scrum
```

And then I added this "use" statement at the top of my controller:

`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;`

Once I did this, my routes started to work.  The I did need to add /scrum to my path, so my complete path turned into:

http://symfony2.localhost/app_dev.php/scrum/my/other/path

Please advise if I have done this correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: you should remove the prefix option. Everything else is correct. Beforfe using a annotation, you need to import it by using the correct use statement. And to let sf know you are using annotations, you need to include the directory as the resource and 'annotations' as the type

Comment: Why is it better to omit the prefix?

Comment: well, I thought you won't want the prefix. It's not a required option, so you can omit it. That is what I was trying to say.

Comment: Ah ok. Sometimes I might want it, just trying to understand if there is a preferred convention.

Comment: If you add an answer with that same info I will accept so you can earn the deserved rep :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to include the routing information into your main routing file. Otherwise, Symfony won't know anything about your routing annotations. This is done by using the same way as including other routing files:

```yaml
# app/routing.yml
acme_demo:
    resource: @AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php
    type: annotation
```

Notice the type 'annotation', this means that Symfony will look for `@Route` annotations. You can also include all controllers of a bundle at once by using `@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/` as resource.

---

Furthermore, annotations are just classes that are initialized in comments. So you need to import the correct namespace by using the `use` statements:

```php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/DemoController.php

// ...
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

// ...
```

---

At last, be sure you didn't turn off the routing annotations. That can be done with something like this:

```
# app/config.yml
sensio_framework_extra:
    router: { annotations: false }
```

If you have something like that, then the routing annotations are **not working**. You need to set it to `true`, the default value.

---

For more information, see the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html